# Google API Geocoding

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I have a problem with google maps api using PHP. I use `file_get_contents` function to do the get request to google, and its work fine. But I if i do a get request with a city with accented letters, it don't work and return me `INVALID_REQUEST`. My example is:

- http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Nardò&sensor=false
- http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Milano&sensor=false

The first don't work, the second work perfectly with file_get_contents. If i do an encode of the url don't work, using urlencode.
Another thing is that if i cut and paste the first url in the browser, it works! So it isn't a problem with google, but i'm wrong something with the encode of the get call from php. Anyone can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#BuildingURLs

Comment: `urlencode()` on the city

Comment: or [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: thanks @geocodezip. I have found the solution on that link. Thanks a lot. I must to encode before in utf-8, then i can use the urlencode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [rawurlencode](https://www.php.net/rawurlencode)?

```
file_get_contents( rawurlencode( $url ) );
```

Comment: Google want the string coded in utf-8, before the urlencode i must to do an utf8-encode of the city. However thanks